# If the "New Adventures of He-Man" is the SAME He-man from Masters of the Universe, WHY is he so much WEAKER?

Tags: powers, he-man

That's...basically it.

You can watch the *Filmation* He-Man and **At least once per episode,** he will do *something* that is *unarguably* super human in his strength; shattering a mountain [or picking it up], drilling through the earth, leaping over a canyon, and tossing so, *so* many bad guys and landmasses:

https://i1.ruliweb.com/ori/17/04/09/15b5105ae5e49c14e.mp4

https://media1.giphy.com/media/4bWNUpAwUf9GE/source.gif

https://media1.giphy.com/media/4bWNUpAwUf9GE/source.gif

[image]

[image]

[enter link description here](https://i1.ruliweb.com/ori/17/04/09/15b5105ae5e49c14e.mp4)

[image]

He did a *lot* to show himself as "the most powerful man in the universe!"

His *The New Adventures* incarnation.... not so much.

This He-Man seemed *far* more dependent upon his [redesigned, sleeker, weaker looking] sword. To his advantage, this sword had more abilities than a Hogworts *wand!;* He-Man could generate blasts of pure fire, light, concussive force, even energy ropes he could swing off, and the sword could *still* cut through [most] stuff with one swipe! So in terms of utility, he had the original matched....

Honestly, I couldn't even *find* a gif of any strength, speed or power feats, though! To my memory, the purest feat of "strength" I saw this He-Man do was catching a 2 man space patrol ship, which was roughly the side of a Bi-plane...and he looked *stressed* for a second when doing it.

Considering this was supposed to be *the same* character, I found his lack of He-Man like strength.... underwhelming.

Then again, i remembered this was far into the future, on a *different* planet (Primus) from Eternia. Perhaps gravity, or time, or distance from Greyskull could have affected his strength on some level.

Was there any in-story reason, explanation or even *hint* as to why that He-Man was so much less strong?